# Adding function is working fine with IE but not with Mozilla

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, validation

I have an issue with Mozilla, i use this client side JavaScript code in .NET for Adding values from one list-box to another. it's working fine with IE but not working with Mozilla 4.0.
any idea where i am wrong? or suggest me with server side script.

function Add()
    {
        debugger;
        var source = document.getElementById('lbLocality');
        var target = document.getElementById('lbSelected');
        var count =  source.length;
        for (var i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var item = source.options[i];         
            if(item.selected)
            {
                source.remove(i);
                target.add(item);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: can you be more specific? Is the function not being called at all? Is there a particular line that doesn't play well with Mozilla? (Do you have firebug installed? so you can troubleshoot javascript in mozilla?)

Comment: the function is called but the debugger doesn't go inside that function. and when i try to add the list-box's item nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add` requires a second argument in Firefox (or other mozilla browsers). The second option determines where you want to add the new item in the select list. Just use `null` to include it at the end.

```
target.add(item, null);
```